# Zend request object redirecting

Tags: zend-framework, response, httpresponse

I ran into an issue with using the response object to go to a different controller upon validation fail.

The setup is one controller(userPages) which calls the action helper (common) which then attempts to verify the user, and if it fails then the user should be sent to another url within the system. the relevant portion of the code is:

```
            /*
             * user was never logged in force them to login now
             * we dont have access to any other helper methods so set it the long hard way...make
             *  sure to specify setDispatched to false to reque the dispatch event
             */
            return $this->getRequest()->setModuleName('default')
                                      ->setControllerName('index')
                                      ->setActionName('login')
                                      ->setDispatched(false);
```

I originally used this snippet in zend 1.6 and php 5.2.3(and it worked perfectly), I mention this because I suspect that things might have gotten slightly more complicated since then, but I cant seem to find anything in the docs that would indicate a need for a different type of redirecting or reasons for failure. Anyone have any ideas? btw: default/index/login is a valid path on my server, and I am certain that it reaches the lines above and successfully sets all parameters before returning and failing silently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so evidently I had a typo when I originally tried the redirector from the action helper, correct syntax for a action helper that inherits from Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract is:

```
//in case we need to redirect preload the redirector
$redirector =  $this->_actionController->getHelper('Redirector');
$redirector->gotoUrl('<your url here>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect from one action to another you can just use:

```
$this->_redirect('/index/login');
```

You can also try [redirector action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html). Hope this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think I have access to action helpers, every time I have tried before I was given a message along the lines of cant use an action helper from within an action helper.

Comment: @xenador. So you want to redirect from your custom action helper, not from action in a controller?